# How to evaluate integral $ I = \int_{all \ space} d^2x / (a^2 + r^2)^3 $ where $ d^2x = dx.dy $ and $ r^2=x^2+y^2 $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is my initial attempt:

1- $ I = \int_{all \ space} d^2x / (a^2 + r^2)^3 $ where $ d^2x = dx.dy $  and $ r^2=x^2+y^2 $

2- Transformation to polar coord. $ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} r.d \theta . dr / (a^2 + r^2)^3 $ . This is an odd function and has also no branch point. I have tried to add a branch point and take a choose a clever contour, but my attempts failed.

For those interested the question is from: An Introduction to Mathematical Methods of Physics (Lorella M. Jones), Section 8 and question 4.

Comment: I had realized that but I am not sure if this is the "right" way. The whole chapter is about complex analysis, so I think there should be a solution using methods of complex analys.

Comment: There is no need to do any of that extra work towards the end. In polar coordinates the function has a simple antiderivative, and given the bounds its status as an odd function has no relevance at all. You've chosen the right method to evaluate the integral, simply execute it to the end.

Comment: I have a complex analysis solution I'm willing to write up and it uses a lesser known theorem that is fun to see - but if you were to ever encounter this problem in the wild, simpler is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the theorem

$$\oint_{\partial D}f(z)\:dz = 2i\iint_D \frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}dxdy$$

and $x^2+y^2 = z\bar{z}$, consider the following integrals

$$\iint\limits_{r\leq|z|\leq R}\frac{dxdy}{(a^2+z\bar{z})^3} = \frac{1}{4i}\oint_{|z|=r}\frac{dz}{z(a^2+z\bar{z})^2} - \frac{1}{4i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{z(a^2+z\bar{z})^2}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(a^2+r^2)^2} - \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(a^2+R^2)^2} = \frac{\pi}{2(a^2+r^2)^2} - \frac{\pi}{2(a^2+R^2)^2}$$

The value of your integral is therefore

$$I = \lim_{r\to0^+}\frac{\pi}{2(a^2+r^2)^2}-\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2(a^2+R^2)^2} = \boxed{\frac{\pi}{2a^4}}$$

Comment: Sometimes I can't differentiate whether I am taking a physics course or a mathematics course... Thanks

Comment: @LadyBeGood I messed up the solution, but when you see that my post has been edited, it will be the fixed version.